# How to align img to the right in <div className="col">

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to align an image to the right inside of a div column.
As you can see it needs to be adjusted slightly to the right.

[image]

```
<div className="main-footer">
<div className="footer-container">
<div className="row">
   <div className="col">
       <h5>GitHub</h5>
       <Navbar.Brand href="https://github.com/">
       <img className="logo-position" src={githublogo} style={{ width: 
        100, height: 100 }} />
       </Navbar.Brand>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
.main-footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #282c34;
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have tried adding some CSS in "logo-position" to fix it, but with no luck. From the answers that I found online I have tried:

```
position: absolute;
right: 38%;
```

```
text-align: right;
```

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Position absolute worked like I wanted it to in the beginning but as soon the window size would change it would move out of position.

I also tried adding `class="pull-right img-responsive"` into the img object, but it didn't seem to do anything.

EDIT: Solved. I simply added some margin to the image before importing it.

Comment: Are you trying to center the github logo inside your `div.col`? What's wrong with `img.logo-position { margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }`?

Comment: Add `float: right;` to the image in your CSS file, it should do the job. ;)

Comment: It doesn't move the image. I updated the question a bit which hopefully will clarify it. @Nogard

Comment: It doesn't move the image. I updated the question a bit which hopefully will clarify it. And yes that is what I'm trying to do. So the image is in the center under the text @DaMahdi03

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
  .col{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    width:120px;
  }
```

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it did not do anything :(

Comment: @Exchange_programming are you sure?  https://codepen.io/shaniemoonlight/pen/PobQYZG

Comment: Yes, I think the reason why it works in that example is because it doesn't include the CSS for main-footer (see question).

Comment: I just added main-footer and it's still centered. https://codepen.io/shaniemoonlight/pen/PobQYZG

Answer (score -1):

.logo-position {
object-fit: contain;

```
object-position: center;
```

}